# Selecting a table by joining on itself and using MIN() and MAX() comparisons

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I posted a similar query earlier on this but I have made some progress with it and have simplified my question. In the following table what script will return for each CARE_ID the row that is the last instance of EVENT_TYPE CP before the first instance of EVENT_TYPE TR in terms of EVENT_DATE. If the value of EVENT_DATE is the same then the tie breaker is EVENT_ID - MAX(EVENT_ID) for CP and MIN(EVENT_ID) for TR. Also here is the expected table that the script should generate. The script has to be compatible with SQL2000.

#### Initial table

```
CARE_ID EVENT_DATE          EVENT_ID  EVENT_TYPE
3       09/04/2010 00:00    117       CP
3       11/04/2010 00:00    104       TR
78      27/07/2009 00:00    11        TR
78      08/12/2010 00:00    706       CP
78      09/12/2010 00:00    707       CP
107     23/02/2010 00:00    93        CP
107     21/09/2012 00:00    1474      TR
364     26/01/2011 00:00    1122      CP
364     18/02/2011 00:00    1136      CP
364     19/02/2011 00:00    569       TR
367     21/06/2010 00:00    151       CP
367     01/07/2010 00:00    247       TR
369     26/07/2010 00:00    248       TR
369     27/07/2010 00:00    152       CP
481     07/09/2010 00:00    63        TR
481     07/09/2010 00:00    194       CP
536     23/08/2010 00:00    225       CP
536     10/09/2010 00:00    135       TR
631     15/12/2009 00:00    256       CP
631     25/12/2009 00:00    147       TR
653     30/09/2010 00:00    360       TR
653     15/10/2010 00:00    295       CP
653     15/10/2010 00:00    298       CP
689     06/10/2010 00:00    372       TR
689     26/10/2010 00:00    307       CP
689     02/11/2010 00:00    306       CP
689     02/11/2010 00:00    370       CP
689     26/08/2011 00:00    1944      CP
689     27/08/2011 00:00    1947      CP
689     22/09/2011 00:00    2125      CP
689     24/09/2012 00:00    2654      CP
689     24/09/2012 00:00    2677      CP
689     06/11/2012 00:00    2720      CP
689     11/11/2012 00:00    2736      CP
689     13/11/2012 00:00    2752      CP
689     15/11/2012 00:00    2765      CP
1066    11/11/2010 00:00    472       TR
1066    23/11/2010 00:00    408       CP
1109    23/12/2010 00:00    428       CP
1109    06/06/2011 00:00    1568      CP
1109    19/07/2011 00:00    958       TR
1199    08/11/2010 00:00    568       CP
1199    19/11/2010 00:00    501       TR
1199    19/11/2010 00:00    511       CP
1199    05/12/2010 00:00    526       CP
1199    16/12/2010 00:00    704       CP
1199    16/12/2010 00:00    705       CP
1199    23/12/2010 00:00    803       CP
1199    24/12/2010 00:00    809       CP
1199    25/12/2010 00:00    923       CP
1199    31/12/2010 00:00    851       CP
1199    04/01/2011 00:00    879       CP
1199    11/01/2011 00:00    926       CP
1199    28/01/2011 00:00    1104      CP
1199    15/02/2011 00:00    1119      CP
1199    25/02/2011 00:00    1144      CP
1199    03/03/2011 00:00    1116      CP
1199    13/03/2011 00:00    1172      CP
1199    30/03/2011 00:00    1331      CP
1199    10/06/2011 00:00    1587      CP
1199    13/06/2011 00:00    1607      CP
1199    14/06/2011 00:00    1604      CP
1199    15/06/2011 00:00    1601      CP
1199    20/06/2011 00:00    1636      CP
1199    28/07/2011 00:00    1726      CP
1199    26/08/2011 00:00    1943      CP
1199    03/09/2011 00:00    1984      CP
1199    21/09/2011 00:00    2064      CP
1199    22/09/2011 00:00    2123      CP
1661    25/01/2011 00:00    216       TR
1661    25/01/2011 00:00    1046      CP
1662    25/01/2011 00:00    220       TR
1662    25/01/2011 00:00    1047      CP
1663    25/01/2011 00:00    97        TR
1663    25/01/2011 00:00    1048      CP
1666    23/01/2011 00:00    100       TR
1666    23/01/2011 00:00    1050      CP
1667    01/02/2011 00:00    227       TR
1667    01/02/2011 00:00    1052      CP
1753    16/02/2011 00:00    326       TR
1781    04/10/2010 00:00    1868      CP
1781    04/10/2010 00:00    1869      CP
1781    04/10/2010 00:00    1870      CP
1781    10/02/2011 00:00    1052      TR
1781    25/03/2011 00:00    1867      CP
1781    20/01/2014 00:00    2103      CP
1841    02/02/2011 00:00    1165      CP
1841    28/02/2011 00:00    597       TR
1887    11/03/2011 00:00    1231      CP
1887    18/03/2011 00:00    607       TR
1938    01/05/2011 00:00    251       TR
2054    12/05/2011 00:00    780       TR
2054    16/07/2011 00:00    1447      CP
2123    09/04/2011 00:00    1434      CP
2123    05/05/2011 00:00    769       TR
2187    20/01/2011 00:00    1475      CP
2187    29/01/2011 00:00    803       TR
2222    11/05/2011 00:00    434       TR
2222    12/05/2011 00:00    1501      CP
2246    31/05/2011 00:00    1536      CP
2246    01/06/2011 00:00    1538      CP
2246    02/06/2011 00:00    1539      CP
2246    20/06/2011 00:00    1637      CP
2246    10/07/2011 00:00    1940      CP
2246    04/08/2011 00:00    1784      CP
2246    14/10/2011 00:00    2170      CP
2246    01/01/2012 00:00    2275      CP
2246    23/03/2012 00:00    2426      CP
2246    01/07/2012 00:00    138       TR
2246    23/07/2012 00:00    2519      CP
2246    24/07/2012 00:00    2542      CP
2246    29/07/2012 00:00    2569      CP
2246    06/08/2012 00:00    2586      CP
2294    12/06/2011 00:00    66        TR
2294    16/07/2011 00:00    1697      CP
2294    17/07/2011 00:00    1698      CP
2456    15/09/2011 00:00    2065      CP
2456    22/09/2011 00:00    2124      CP
2456    27/09/2012 00:00    2669      CP
2456    29/11/2013 00:00    3218      CP
2456    02/12/2013 00:00    1694      TR
2456    03/12/2013 00:00    3234      CP
2456    04/12/2013 00:00    3235      CP
2456    29/01/2014 00:00    3340      CP
2512    17/09/2011 00:00    2049      CP
2512    25/01/2012 00:00    628       TR
2630    03/09/2011 00:00    1982      CP
2630    13/05/2013 00:00    834       TR
2630    13/05/2013 00:00    3064      CP
2691    22/09/2011 00:00    2135      CP
2691    12/01/2014 00:00    906       TR
2694    20/04/2011 00:00    2053      CP
2694    30/04/2011 00:00    1112      TR
2759    07/11/2011 00:00    1165      TR
2759    31/12/2011 00:00    2280      CP
2759    01/01/2012 00:00    2276      CP
2759    06/01/2012 00:00    2272      CP
2759    08/01/2012 00:00    2274      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2271      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2273      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2277      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2278      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2279      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2281      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2282      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2283      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2284      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2285      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2286      CP
2759    09/01/2012 00:00    2287      CP
2759    10/01/2012 00:00    2289      CP
2759    09/02/2012 00:00    2377      CP
2773    13/10/2011 00:00    2154      CP
2773    24/01/2013 00:00    2920      CP
2773    25/01/2013 00:00    1430      TR
2773    14/02/2013 00:00    2946      CP
2858    27/10/2011 00:00    2209      CP
2858    08/11/2011 00:00    1167      TR
2894    15/11/2011 00:00    586       TR
2894    27/09/2012 00:00    2700      CP
2961    14/02/2012 00:00    642       TR
2961    18/04/2012 00:00    2592      CP
2961    01/08/2012 00:00    2591      CP
3178    08/08/2012 00:00    780       TR
3178    01/09/2012 00:00    2610      CP
3178    08/09/2012 00:00    2611      CP
3311    11/09/2012 00:00    796       TR
3311    11/09/2012 00:00    2891      CP
3311    22/01/2013 00:00    2909      CP
3311    11/02/2013 00:00    2941      CP
3311    12/02/2013 00:00    2943      CP
3311    10/04/2014 00:00    3544      CP
3344    01/03/2013 00:00    868       TR
3344    03/05/2013 00:00    3045      CP
3362    08/02/2013 00:00    808       TR
3362    11/02/2014 00:00    3409      CP
3362    12/02/2014 00:00    2980      CP
3426    08/04/2013 00:00    2986      CP
3426    20/04/2013 00:00    3006      CP
3426    22/05/2013 00:00    3086      CP
3426    13/07/2013 00:00    474       TR
3426    02/10/2013 00:00    3217      CP
3426    04/12/2013 00:00    3236      CP
3674    12/01/2014 00:00    168       TR
3674    17/04/2014 00:00    3561      CP
3675    13/01/2014 00:00    3293      CP
3675    27/03/2014 00:00    939       TR
3770    08/01/2014 00:00    917       TR
3770    09/04/2014 00:00    3379      CP
3797    25/02/2014 00:00    3431      CP
3797    26/02/2014 00:00    931       TR
3805    04/03/2014 00:00    1782      TR
3805    04/03/2014 00:00    3447      CP
3805    25/03/2014 00:00    3476      CP
3901    15/02/2014 00:00    3584      CP
3901    03/03/2014 00:00    1820      TR
3907    05/01/2014 00:00    3591      CP
3907    09/01/2014 00:00    945       TR
3907    14/01/2014 00:00    3592      CP
3907    14/01/2014 00:00    3593      CP
```

#### Final table — results

```
CARE_ID EVENT_DATE          EVENT_ID    EVENT_TYPE
3       09/04/2010 00:00    117         CP
107     23/02/2010 00:00    93          CP
364     18/02/2011 00:00    1136        CP
367     21/06/2010 00:00    151         CP
536     23/08/2010 00:00    225         CP
631     15/12/2009 00:00    256         CP
1109    06/06/2011 00:00    1568        CP
1199    08/11/2010 00:00    568         CP
1781    04/10/2010 00:00    1870        CP
1841    02/02/2011 00:00    1165        CP
1887    11/03/2011 00:00    1231        CP
2123    09/04/2011 00:00    1434        CP
2187    20/01/2011 00:00    1475        CP
2246    23/03/2012 00:00    2426        CP
2456    29/11/2013 00:00    3218        CP
2512    17/09/2011 00:00    2049        CP
2630    03/09/2011 00:00    1982        CP
2691    22/09/2011 00:00    2135        CP
2694    20/04/2011 00:00    2053        CP
2773    24/01/2013 00:00    2920        CP
2858    27/10/2011 00:00    2209        CP
3426    22/05/2013 00:00    3086        CP
3675    13/01/2014 00:00    3293        CP
3797    25/02/2014 00:00    3431        CP
3901    15/02/2014 00:00    3584        CP
3907    05/01/2014 00:00    3591        CP
```

Here is the script that has given me my initial table

```
SELECT  CARE_ID ,
        EVENT_DATE ,
        EVENT_ID ,
        EVENT_TYPE
INTO    #t1
FROM    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
WHERE   EVENT_TYPE IN ( 'BR', 'CH', 'TE', 'SU' )
        AND EVENT_DATE IS NOT NULL
        AND CARE_ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                CARE_ID
                         FROM   vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
                         WHERE  EVENT_TYPE = 'CP' )
ORDER BY CARE_ID ,
        EVENT_DATE ,
        EVENT_ID

SELECT  CARE_ID ,
        EVENT_DATE ,
        EVENT_ID ,
        'TR' AS EVENT_TYPE
FROM    ( SELECT    #t1.CARE_ID ,
                    #t1.EVENT_DATE ,
                    MIN(#t1.EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_ID
          FROM      #t1
                    JOIN ( SELECT   CARE_ID ,
                                    MIN(EVENT_DATE) AS minx
                           FROM     #t1
                           GROUP BY CARE_ID
                         ) tmin ON #t1.CARE_ID = tmin.CARE_ID
                                   AND #t1.EVENT_DATE = tmin.minx
          GROUP BY  #t1.CARE_ID ,
                    #t1.EVENT_DATE
        ) a
WHERE   EVENT_DATE IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT  CARE_ID ,
        EVENT_DATE ,
        EVENT_ID ,
        EVENT_TYPE
FROM    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
WHERE   EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
        AND EVENT_DATE IS NOT NULL
        AND CARE_ID IN ( SELECT CARE_ID
                         FROM   ( SELECT    #t1.CARE_ID ,
                                            #t1.EVENT_DATE ,
                                            MIN(#t1.EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_ID
                                  FROM      #t1
                                            JOIN ( SELECT   CARE_ID ,
                                                            MIN(EVENT_DATE) AS minx
                                                   FROM     #t1
                                                   GROUP BY CARE_ID
                                                 ) tmin ON #t1.CARE_ID = tmin.CARE_ID
                                                           AND #t1.EVENT_DATE = tmin.minx
                                  GROUP BY  #t1.CARE_ID ,
                                            #t1.EVENT_DATE
                                ) b )
ORDER BY CARE_ID ,
        EVENT_DATE ,
        EVENT_ID

DROP TABLE #t1
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: what if there is no `CP` before the first `TR`?

Comment: @Jodrell Then a row for that CARE_ID will not be returned

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Sure can I pm you with the script as it won't fit in this dialogue box

Comment: If the value of EVENT_DATE is the same as of which record? Of one that has EVENT_TYPE=TR?

Comment: Just edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @Lesya - If a CARE_ID has more than one instance of TR with the same value of EVENT_DATE then the row to be used in the comparison is the one with the MIN(EVENT_ID). If the script returns more than one row for a CARE_ID because there is more than one instance of CP because they have the same EVENT_DATE then the row to be considered is the one with the MAX(EVENT_ID).

Answer (score 0):

Well this is going to help,

```
SELECT
    [CARE_ID], 
    min([EVENT_DATE]) FirstTRDate
FROM
    [Initial]
WHERE
    [EVENT_TYPE] = 'TR'
GROUP BY
    [CARE_ID]
```

Thats going to give you the First TR Date for each Care Id. So,

```
SELECT
    [CARE_ID],
    [EVENT_DATE],
    [EVENT_ID]
FROM
    [Initial] I
JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [CARE_ID], 
            min([EVENT_DATE]) FirstTRDate
        FROM
            [Initial]
        WHERE
            [EVENT_TYPE] = 'TR'
        GROUP BY
            [CARE_ID]
    ) FirstTP
    ON FirstTP.[CARE_ID] = I.[CARE_ID]
WHERE
    I.[EVENT_TYPE] = 'CP' AND
    I.[EVENT_DATE] <= FirstTP.[EVENT_DATE]
```

Will give you all CPs that occur before or at the same date as the first TP.

Now, for me to go further, I'm going to have to better understand your question I feel like the extra effort is mirrored.